# Meal plan algorithm

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I've been trying to use the knapsack problem to solve a particular domain. Given a constraint of:

- Calories (e.g 300)
- No of meals (e.g. 3)

I want to create the optimum meal plan from a search space of about 100,000 recipes. Each recipe is an object with the following properties:

```
public class Recipe {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private double calories;
}
```

How could I approach this problem using the knapsack problem? I've been looking at the code from [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/the-knapsack-problem/), and I am stumped at how to implement my constraints.

```
class Knapsack {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int val[] = {10, 40, 30, 50};
        int wt[] = {5, 4, 6, 3};   
        int W = 10;   
        System.out.println(knapsack(val, wt, W));    
   }

    public static int knapsack(int val[], int wt[], int W) {
        int N = wt.length;
        int[][] V = new int[N + 1][W + 1];

        for (int col = 0; col <= W; col++) {
            V[0][col] = 0;
        }

        for (int row = 0; row <= N; row++) {
            V[row][0] = 0;
        }

        for (int item=1;item<=N;item++){    
            for (int weight=1;weight<=W;weight++){
                if (wt[item-1]<=weight){
                    V[item][weight]=Math.max (val[item-1]+V[item-1][weight-wt[item-1]], V[item-1][weight]);
                }
                else {
                    V[item][weight]=V[item-1][weight];
                }
            }

        }

        for (int[] rows : V) {
            for (int col : rows) {
                System.out.format("%5d", col);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return V[N][W];
    }
}
```

Comment: Find a meal that is exactly 100 calories. Eat three times a day forever, with no variation.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your goal but I don't think the "knapsack problem" applies. How are you defining an "optimum meal plan"? Are you trying to find a set of 3 meals with the maximum amount of calories?

Comment: @P.Pascal hopefully this is clearer. I have a search space of 100k recipes, user says they want a plan of x (eg 3) recipes with y (eg 1200) total calories altogether, I want to find all possible combination of recipes that meet this requirement. So for example, would expecting result to be 1) recipe 1 - 300, recipe 2 - 300, recipe 3 - 600, 2) recipe 1 - 600, recipe 2 - 400, recipe 3 - 200... from there I can optimise further

Comment: Is your recipe List sorted?

Comment: No not sorted at all